# Can I get a forloop in an .append(), that already is in a forloop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a Table based on "width"(columns) and "height"(rows) but I just can't get it right.
So is there Something wrong with my code?

Code:

```
for(var i=0;i<width;i++){
        $('#map').append(
            '<tr>'+
                for(var e=0;e<height;e++){

                }
            +'</tr>'
        );
    };
```

Comment: Yes, your code is invalid. you can't have a for loop there.

Comment: Sweet mother mercy, that is not an efficient (or valid) use of `append`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is invalid, you can't have a for loop there. Try rearranging it a bit.

```
var html;
for(var i=0;i<width;i++){
    html = '<tr>';
    for(var e=0;e<height;e++){
        html += "<td>foo"+e+"</td>";
    }
    html +='</tr>'
    $('#map').append(html);
};
```

or even better:

```
var html = "";
for(var i=0;i<width;i++){
    html += '<tr>';
    for(var e=0;e<height;e++){
        html += "<td>foo"+e+"</td>";
    }
    html +='</tr>';
};
$('#map').append(html);
```

Comment: Since I'm micro-optimizing everyone's answers, why not push all the strings into an `Array` and do a `join()`? ;-)

Comment: @Mathletics, that would make it slower I bet :). And, I also bet it is browser dependent

Comment: @Mathletics 5 years ago, that would have been a good idea. Modern day browsers there is hardly a benefit and is most likely a lot slower in chrome.

Comment: @epascarello oh snap, I didn't know that trick had been invalidated!

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically create the `<tr>` element and append the `<td>` elements to it instead.

```
var table = [];
for(var i = 0, $tr; i < height; i++){
  $tr = $("<tr/>");
  for(var j = 0; j < width; j++){
    $tr.append("<td/>");
  )
  table.push($tr);
}
$map.append(table);
```

**UPDATE:** Optimized for DOM access.

Comment: You're still accessing the DOM once for every `width`, instead of _exactly once_.

Comment: `$map.append($tr)` is still inside a for loop in the edit I'm seeing.

Comment: The dimensions are swapped ~.~

Comment: Yeah, you're using `append` `width*height` times when you can get away with only using it once.

Comment: I wonder if that's micro-optimization. That's why I didn't edit that part

Comment: That depends on how many rows we're talking about, it could make a huge difference in IE8 with 500 rows vs 10

Comment: Right, you'd show 500 rows at once. Anyways, even if I did by now anyone would jump on me. I'll let it be

Comment: I don't see a compelling reason to access the DOM _more_ than once, and this guy could use the tip, so why not do it "right"?

Comment: There you go. I optimized the DOM access for the record. What about using pure JavaScript now? :)

Comment: If i changed one line in my answer, it would be pure javascript. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < height; i++){
  var row = "<tr>";
  for(var j=0; j < width; j++){
    row += "<td>Something data</td>";
  }
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#map').append(row)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery way to do what you're doing is like so:

```
var $table = $('<tbody />');

for(var i = 0; i < width; i++){
  $tr = $("<tr/>");
  for(var e = 0; e < height; e++){
    $tr.append("<td/>");
  );
  $table.append($tr);
};

$('#map').append($table);
```

That way you are only accessing the DOM **once**.